# Using filter with offset

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet with a number of columns and tick boxes. I want the Table header to be displayed and joined together when the boxes are ticked in each row. For example looking at the screenshot below:-
In the result for John in row 2, I would want to have a Red and Green joined in Cell M2.

Currently have got this formula to pull filter the boxes that are TRUE
`=IFERROR(JOIN(" ",FILTER(B2:L2,B2:L2=TRUE)),"")` but cant seem to work out the rest. I'm fairly sure the offset function is probably needed or a query may be easier?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

formula:

```
=BYROW(B2:L,LAMBDA(bx,INDEX(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(bx=TRUE,B$1:L$1,)))))
```

- 

[image]

Comment: That's perfect, appreciate your quick response. Wouldn't have ever got to that answer!

Comment: @Tom If you find the answer helpful then please mark the answer as accepted (tick mark the answer to accept it). Accept means your problem is solved and other visitor can know the thread is closed. You may also use `=BYROW(B2:INDEX(L2:L,COUNTA(A2:A)),LAMBDA(bx,INDEX(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(B$1:L$1,bx=TRUE)))))`

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,If(B2:L2,OFFSET(B2:L2,-row()+1,),)))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply